# what is the meaning of "Could not locate BSP definition for <machine>/standard" yocto error message?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to understand why my custom yocto bsp layer is giving me the following error when I try to build kernel:

```
linux-cip-5.10-cip29+gitAUTOINC+909c54bf68-r0 do_kernel_metadata: Could not locate BSP definition for custom_machine/standard and no defconfig was provided
```

I basically created a meta layer with a machine definition for armv8-2a i.e arm 64 cortexa55 TUNE.

At this stage I just want it to build the kernel from my github repo. However, the command `MACHINE=custom_machine bitbake linux-cip` causes the above error. I have not defined recipe-bsp as that is not the target build artifact. I just want kernel and rootfs.
My metal layer has:

`recipes-kernel/linux/linux-cip_5.10.bb`

which mostly has:

```
SRC_URI = "git://git@gitlab.com/cip-project/cip-kernel/linux-cip.git;protocol=ssh;branch=linux-5.10.y-cip"

PV = "5.10-cip29+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
PROVIDES = "virtual/kernel"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git/kernel"


COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "custom_machine"

#KBUILD_DEFCONFIG = "defconfig"
#KCONFIG_MODE = "alldefconfig"

EXTRA_OEMAKE:append:task-install = " -C ${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR} M=${S}"
```

What is going on here?